# Accessing session environment from powershell script/module

Tags: powershell, session, powershell-3.0

The PowerCli (VMWares powershell module) has a command: Connect-VIServer

You run `Connect-VIServer -Server myserver -credentials (get-credentials)`

After running that future powercli cmdlets in that session use that connection.

How do I do something like this with my own modules?

I want to have a command I could run like `Connect-MyDB -Server mydb -Credentials (get-credentials)`

How functions in my module access the server and $credentials variables when I run them in the session?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to define module global variables within `psm1` file and not export it afterwards. Alternatively you can use global variable.

As an example you can check out my [TFS REST module](https://github.com/majkinetor/TFS). It uses `global:tfs` for connection settings but internally all functions use few variables defined in script [_global.ps1](https://github.com/majkinetor/TFS/blob/master/_globals.ps1) which are dot sourced from withint psm1 file.